# Local Binary Pattern Logic

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a doubt regarding the histogram on the LBP algorithm.
Let's say I have an image that is 1000x1000 and I split this image into 4 sub-images of 250x250 each so as far as I know I should compute each sub-image histogram generating a histogram vector of 59 positions (Uniform LBP version).

My doubt is, the Wikipedia article says I have to concatenate each histogram vector to generate the feature vector so the feature vector of my image is a vector with 236 positions ? 59 positions * 4 sub-images.

Is it wrong to compute the whole image and generate just one 59 position histogram vector as my feature vector?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With more splitting you get more information about the image: what are the textures on different parts of the image. Without splitting, you get only an average texture. Just imagine you want to recognize a cat from a histogram, or from an image with 100*100 pixels.

Comment: Is this still true if I want to discriminate terrain? I have a class for grass texture and a class for asphalt texture, the thing is: I'm trying to classify these types of textures and my classification algorithm is missing a lot when I use another dataset that wasn't generated by my LBP the classification algorithm can discriminate with a good percentage of hits so I can only assume my LBP is not doing what it should and I'm not slicing the image and concatenating the feature vectors, I thought that since I want to classify the whole thing as texture A or B I could do it like that.

Comment: If the pictures are all homogenous you can skip the splitting. But if you train a classifier in this way, then give it a cat (what is not homogenous), it could be easily classified as asphalt based on the histogram, while with more resolution (splitting) the classifier would detect the inhomogeneity. Anyway, if your classifier performs differently during training and testing, then your training dataset is insufficient.

Comment: I see, I'm just thinking about how long it will take to classify everything if I split my image on 4 sub-images I have a feature vector of 236 positions (237 if I count the label field), but if I split my image into 10 sub-images this feature vector grows to 590 positions and this is just for one image! That's why I thought I understood it wrong when the article says "concatenate each histogram"

Comment: You can use other features. Eg. if you want to recognize only homogeneous images, you don't need the 4 sub-images, only the information that they are similar or not. So, besides the whole image histogram, the dispersion of the sub-image histograms can be sufficient.

Comment: I see, well, thank you very much for your patience , you helped me a lot!